# Mutex locking and unlocking time difference

Tags: c++, multithreading

I'm new to multithread programming. I have a simple testing program:

```
#include <mutex>
#include <thread>
#include <iostream>
int main(){
    std::mutex mtx;
    std::thread t1([&](){
        while (true){
            mtx.lock();
            std::cout << 1 << "Hello" << "\n";
            mtx.unlock();
        }
    });
    std::thread t2([&](){
        while (true){
            mtx.lock();
            std::cout << 2 << "Hello" << "\n";
            mtx.unlock();
        }
    });
    t1.join();
    t2.join();
}
```

This is a pretty simple program, and it prints "1Hello" and "2Hello" in a random pattern, which implies that the mutex is unlocked by one and then acquired by the other and executed, in some random pattern.

Is it specified behavior in standard, that is, will a implementation guarantee that it won't stick to t1? And if not, how do I avoid it?

Comment: No need to *assume* that `t1` unlocks the mutex. Just read the code! Also, it seems you need to read up on modern *preemptive* multitasking and how it works.

Comment: I don't think the standard guarantees it, but in practice, yes both will be executed.

Comment: can you clarify EXACTLY what is your question (maybe add some prompt), because I just don't get :(
the question is to broad to answer here + I think after you need to read short guide on multi-threads \ race-condition\ dead-lock\live-lock etc. you will be able answer to your self those types of questions (been there done that :) )

Comment: @LordTitiKaka, Thanks for your advice. But isn't a dead lock means there's at least a resource cycle in the program (so that none can proceed), and it's not the case, or is it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There should be no guarantee of who will be running.  If you can set the priority of one thread higher than the other, then you can guarantee with this code that only the highest priority thread will be running.

What is the actual problem?  The problem is that this code uses multi-threading in the worst possible way.  This is quite an achievement and not really bad because it is an exercise.  It asks the threads to run continuously, it locks while doing long actions and only unlocks for the next loop, so there is actually no parallelism, only a battle for the mutex.

How can this be solved?  Let the threads do some background action and then stop or let the threads wait for a condition are at least let the threads sleep once in a while AND let the threads run as independent as possible and not block others while doing potentially a long action.

---

Edit (small clarification): while this code is using multi-threading in the worst possible way, it is a nice and clean example on how to do it.

Comment: Yes, that a program with its full code being critical section shall not be parallelized... So but what about a more general case, that several threads do the same job (say, sleep), and have little part protected by mutex, it's actually the same (isn't it?), only changed the probability that OS won't stick to one.

Comment: The scheduler gives time to those threads that are active, so if enough threads sleep (wait for a timeout or for some condition), then there should be no problem.  When more threads are active for a longer time, the scheduler can do some fair scheduling and assign time slices to the different threads (on single-core, multi-core is a bit more complex) but this is handled by the OS, not by C++.